# I don't want to store any data in hadoop master node. Is that possible?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, cluster-computing, datanode

I have a multinode hadoop cluster setup. 1 master server and 25 slave nodes. The size of the master node is 2T whereas the slaves are 18T each. So I don't want a datanode in my master server because it may cause storage issues in the future. How can I configure that? I tried removing Master from slaves file in conf but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want a Datanode on the Namenode host, then just don't start the datanode process there. In general, it would not be good practice to share a datanode and namenode on the same host.

Comment: Is there a provision to start datanode and namenode separately? I am using start-dfs.sh to start hdfs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ambari to manage your cluster you can [decommission the datanode](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.5.0/managing-and-monitoring-ambari/content/amb_decommission_a_datanode.html) on your master node.  I'm also concerned you only have 1 master node. But that's a problem for another day.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. I am not using Ambari but I guess there would be a way to decommission a datanode in HDFS web UI. Also, ya I am planning to add one more master node